# What is server side rendering?

Tags: c#, windows

What is server side rendering and what technologies are available for development on windows operating systems.

I have an application that uses .Net remoting to communicate with a client app and would like to remove all dependancy on this .Net component by replacing it with a server side rendering solution. The application is rich with 2D visuals, with an active X chart conrol that updates roughly once a second. I've noticed that tearing occurs on the active x control when remoting to the app with windows remote desktop.

Comment: something to view: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0bbKSQ1S2k